# CakePHP 3.0 - Unable to use select on a contain

Tags: sql, cakephp-3.0

I am experimenting with CakePHP 3.0 for a project - unfortunately it uses a legacy database so I am unable to rely on conventional table/field names.

I have three tables, TIT (Titles), AUT (Authors) and TAUT. TAUT is a join table for TIT and AUT.

The AUT table is configured as follows:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('AUT');
        $this->displayField('SALUTATION');
        $this->primaryKey('AUTNO');
        $this->belongsToMany('Titles', [
            'foreignKey' => 'AUTNO',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'TITNO',
            'joinTable' => 'TAUT'
        ]);
    }
```

and TIT:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('TIT');
        $this->displayField('TITLE');
        $this->primaryKey('TITNO');
        $this->belongsToMany('Authors', [
            'foreignKey' => 'TITNO',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'AUTNO',
            'joinTable' => 'TAUT'
        ]);
    }
```

When I run the following query:

```
$query = $this->Titles->find()
    ->select(['TITNO','TITLE'])
    ->contain([
        'Authors' => function ($q) {
            return $q
                ->select(['Authors.AUTNO','Authors.SALUTATION']);
        }
    ]);
```

I get the data I want through two queries, but the select method on Authors does not seem to work - the resulting query pulls every single field from the table instead of just the ones in the method. The first select *does* work and the query only includes the fields requested.

Is there something wrong with my config here, or my query code itself? I suspect this is a result of using a legacy database with poor naming but if there is any way to fix it I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a bug, please open a ticket in github

Comment: Hi José, thanks to your comment I was able to find a closed issue on github: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5959
By attaching a 'fields' key to the contain I was able to limit the selection.